# Load balance 2 DSL routers using a 3rd(4 LAN, 1 WAN port router)?

Tags: networking, router, openwrt

I would like to install open-WRT on a router MR3420  v 2.3 and want to know if it can act as Load balancer for 2 DSL routers below. but I am not sure if openWRT will solve the following use-case
I have two DSL connections providing internet

1. Unreliable - 4MB (Router has 4 LAN and 1 WAN ports )
2. Reliable but only 2MB (This router has only 2 LAN ports available)

And an extra 3rd router (4 LANS , 1 WAN,  MR3420 v 2.3) on which I want to install openwrt and use it as a load balancing router for the above DSL routers so that I can smoothly browse internet without switching WiFi frequently.

**Question:** 
MR3420  has only one WAN port and my assumption is it should have 2 WAN ports to support the two DSL connections above? am I right ? or Can I plug the cables from the DSL routers into the LAN ports of the 3rd router and yet use it as Load balancing router using openWRT ?

Answer (score 0):

On MR3420's firmware, it's definitely a WAN port, but I doubt it would be different to the other ports from hardware aspect. So, I suggest you to search about open-WRT and see if it supports binding ports to custom network zones. If so, then you can choose 2 ports as a WAN port.

But... What if you replace MR3420 with 1 of your main routers, then **load balance between WAN and DSL**, instead 2 WANs??

Comment: I have just installed openwrt on it and discovered that it can make the router act as client and create new WAN interface by wirelessly connecting to an existing hotspot (in my case one of my DSL modems) However I can not seem to install multiwan3 on it due to space issue, I am trying to sort it now

Comment: Ok, but I still recommend to use only 2 modems to load-balance between DSL and WAN. I guess it reduces the latency.